# Find cell match if it is followed by another cell match

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that is a list of meeting transcripts converted from PDF using `pdftools` with a series of unnested words that look like this:

`document_id <- c("BOARD19810203meeting.pdf", "BOARD19810405meeting.pdf", "BOARD19810609meeting.pdf", "BOARD19810405meeting.pdf", "BOARD19810609meeting.pdf")`

`word <- c("leave", "tomorrow", "for", "first", meeting")`

`df <- data.frame(document_id, word)`

I want to write a code that aggregates the number of times a word appears only if it is followed by another word by the date that it appears on. Using the example above, I would like to count how many times 'leave tomorrow' appears (i.e. count leave if followed by tomorrow). So the final output would look like this:

`date <- c("1981-02-03", "1982-08-09", "1991-04-04", "1991-07-04")`

`word <- c("leave", "leave", "leave", "leave")`

`df <- data.frame(date, word)`

I have written the following code to aggregate one of the terms:

`leave_in_transcripts <- select(interview_transcripts, 1:3) %>% filter(grepl("leave", word, ignore.case=TRUE)|(grepl("tomorrow", word, ignore.case=TRUE))`

`leave_in_transcripts$word <- str_count(leave_in_transcripts$word, 'leave')`

`count_leave <- aggregate(leave_in_transcripts['word'], by = list(Group.date = leave_in_transcripts$date), sum, na.rm=T)`

But obviously this just counts leave even if it is followed by another word.

I have been searching for a while and I can't quite figure out what to do. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes sorry. Just done. Is that clear?

Comment: Just made both 5 rows long. Sorry about that!

Comment: So the idea is that i want to count leave IF it is followed by tomorrow. So the expected output should just be a string of "leave" repeated but of course only if it's followed by "tomorrow", which my current code doesn't do.

Comment: May be you need to use `lead` `df %>% mutate(i1 = str_detect(word, 'leave') & str_detect(lead(word), 'tomorrow'))` but as I said it is not clear for me with the expected output

Comment: The actual columns are 1.7m rows long. Leave is repeated about 1400 times. So I'm not really sure how to alter my code to reflect exactly what I have. I just want to count the number of times a word is repeated if the cell below it has a specific word in it. Do you know how to do that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205035/discussion-between-newtorcode-and-akrun).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can count the number of instances of 'leave' followed by 'tomorrow' by creating a logical expression with current row and the next row (`lead`) and `sum` the logical vector

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
 summarise(Sum = sum(str_detect(word, 'leave') &
         str_detect(lead(word), 'tomorrow'), na.rm = TRUE))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun 
For anyone else reading this, I also wrote code to aggregate the instances that words appear:
`leave_in_transcripts <- df %>% mutate(match = str_detect(word, 'leave') & str_detect(lead(word), 'tomorrow'))`

`leave_in_transcripts <- select(leave_in_transcripts, 1:4) %>% filter(match == "TRUE")`

`leave_in_transcripts$match <- str_count(leave_in_transcripts$match, 'TRUE')`

`count_leave <- aggregate(leave_in_transcripts['match'], by = list(Group.date = leave_in_transcripts$date), sum, na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @akrun for answering this. 
For anyone else reading this, I also wrote code to aggregate by date the instances that words appear based on Akrun's code:

`leave_in_transcripts <- df %>% mutate(match = str_detect(word, 'leave') & str_detect(lead(word), 'tomorrow'))`

`leave_in_transcripts <- select(leave_in_transcripts, 1:4) %>% filter(match == "TRUE")`

`leave_in_transcripts$match <- str_count(leave_in_transcripts$match, 'TRUE')`

`count_leave <- aggregate(leave_in_transcripts['match'], by = list(Group.date = leave_in_transcripts$date), sum, na.rm=T)`

Answer (score 1):

In base R, we can use `head` and `tail` to match values for current and next rows. We can `subset` the rows which match the condition and use `as.Date` to convert data from `document_id` to date object giving appropriate format. Also since you want to test for an exact match and not partial match it is better to use `==` and not `grepl`.

```
transform(subset(df, c(head(word, -1) == "leave" & 
                       tail(word, -1) == "tomorrow", FALSE)), 
                 date = as.Date(document_id,"BOARD%Y%m%dmeeting.pdf"))

#               document_id  word       date
#1 BOARD19810203meeting.pdf leave 1981-02-03
```

If you just want to count number of times the above condition is satisfied, we can use `sum`.

```
with(df, sum(head(word, -1) == "leave" & tail(word, -1) == "tomorrow"))
```